# Highchart - Chart type, gap in the x and y axis (0,0)

Tags: highcharts

Please refer the fiddle `code`http://jsfiddle.net/yuvarajkumarg/az290eyq/1/

In Highchart of type Chart, when we plot for height = 0 and pressure = 2, we get a gap as shown in jsfiddle. I want point to be plotted on the X-axis(2,0). But the graph looks like it is plotted on (2,2) since the y-axis plot starts way above the x-axis.  How to remove the gap ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the categorized axis. 
There are probably a few ways around the issue, but I would do it this way (on your xAxis):

```
tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
min:0.5,
max:6.5
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/az290eyq/2/

You could also do it by not using categories, and using the axis label formatter in order to display the numeric sequence that you need.

**[[ edit for comments:**

For the min and max values - the x axis values for a categorized axis are the category array index values.  So the first category is x = 0, the second is x = 1, etc.

Because Highcharts puts the the label in the center of the value's space, setting the min/max to the actual min/max value +/- 0.5 will align the center of the space with the start/end of the axis.

So, you can calculate this dynamically by using 0.5 for the min, and counting the categories array and using (count -1.5) as the max.

Additionally, setting the `tickmarkPlacement` proerty to 'on' moves the tick mark to the center of the space as well, aligning the ticks with the start/end of the axis as well.

Comment: It works .Thank you so much . can you please explain how you arrived at the min and max values

Comment: Updated answer with explanation.